# How to detect thread-safe in your API？

Tags: c, multithreading

It's often that you need to `extern` some C APIs like this:

```
set_module_callback(module, some_func, func_args);
```

But the `module` need the `some_func` to be *thread-safe*, i.e., there maybe more than 1 threads to call this function, but I don't know whether it was *thread-safe*, is there some way to test that while calling `set_module_callback`?

Answer (score 2):

Thread-safety is very complicated domain. You can get unsafety from many aspects, even well protected code can potentially have a holes in communication with another piece of codes. That is why it is better to assume that `some_func` is unsafe and provide (for example) critical section around shared resources.
So answer is 'no'

Comment: This is probably the most practical approach for generically supporting unknown extern functions.  Assume they're not thread safe, and wrap the calls.  Not ideal performance-wise possibly, but probably the more credible approach.

Answer (score 0):

I see no way to automatically have some piece of code test another piece of code.

In order for you to really be sure ti is thread-safe, you will have to go in and look at it/analyze what it does and where side-effects could arise/add a mutex where needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a POSIX one, you could give a try to the [Helgrind tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) which does some concurrent access detection.

But it is based on how your software calls the APIs. So you won't have an absolute general answer if yes or no your APIs are thread safe. You will only have this answer given a specific application.